# Why my state argument when creating my Redux-Reducer is not being updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, switch-statement

Help, My first time linking Redux to React.

My state argument has been passed with  value but when in the `switch` statement the values assigned to the `state` is not read at `return` as the original value `hello` but the values from the return statement after it the `No` value becomes the initial then `ADD`.

when the page loads it shows state has the value of hello, but when I send an action the value of state changes to 'No'

**This is my code**

```
const MessageReducer = (state = "hello", action) => {
alert(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      // state.;
      alert(state);
      return "ADD";
    default:
      return "No";
  }
};
export default MessageReducer;
```

**this is my configure store:**

```
import MessageReducer from "../reducers/messageReducer";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { preview: MessageReducer },
});
```

**my makdown.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MsgCreator from "../actions/msgAction";

class Markdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      current: event.target.value,
    });
    this.props.input(this.state.current);
  }
  render() {
    let i = this.props.messages;
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label for="editor">Enter your text here: </label>
          <textarea
            id="editor"
            name="editor"
            value={this.props.current}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          ></textarea>
        </form>
        <p id="preview">{i}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    messages: state.preview,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    input: (input) => {
      dispatch(MsgCreator(input));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Markdown);
```

**My App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Markdown from "./components/markdown";
import "./App.css";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <Markdown />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does Alert work?

Comment: @CoraSphinx yes the alert works, when the page loads it shows state has the value of hello, but when I send an action the value of state changes to 'No'

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t see yow Provider={store} anywhere

```
<Provider store={store}>
<App/>
</Provider>
```

Comment: Another thing that might be causing this issue is that before you  call yow action you is setting the local state with a new value… when updating the state generates a rendering, so you uptake the local state, it triggers a re render then you exec your action with the local state property which might not have the new value by the time you exec the action, as the updating state function runs async. Ether remove the local state or set the same parameter to both functions

Comment: I have removed the local state I used only the redux own. From my struggle to debug it shows the `state` changes to new value (string) while in the `switch case`.

Comment: I have updated the code to something like this now but shows the `typeof` changes from an `object` to a `string`

Comment: `const MessageReducer = (state = { data: "" }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      alert(typeof state);
      state.data = action.input;
      return state.data;
    default:
      return state.data;
  }`